# Is there a system to brute force a combination padlock?

Tags: combinatorics, locks

Our escape room recently acquired some old lockers with a couple of these combination padlocks on them. Unfortunately, the seller didn't know the code.

Is there a mathematical system in cycling through the possible solutions? The code is 5 of the numbers between 0 and 9. The order of the numbers doesn't matter and each number can only appear once, which should narrow it down a lot.

[image]

Comment: There are 15120 possible combinations if no number repeats. Otherwise, there are 387420489 of them.

Comment: I suppose you could start by trying to analyse which keys seem more worn out, or seem to have more fingerprints, or just seem softer to press. That might give you a starting point in narrowing down which numbers are more likely to be a part of the combination. Once you can narrow those down to 5, it's a very simple process to try different combinations of those numbers

Comment: @NapoleonofPuzzling Is it really that many? Even when considering that there's no difference between 12345 and 54321?

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t notice the ‘order of the numbers doesn’t matter’ part.

Comment: If the order does not matter, then there are only $10!/(5!^2)=252$ possibilities. That should be easy to cycle through in twenty minutes or so.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, 5 keys must be down for the lock to open up. That narrows your possibilities down quite significantly, and if my hand-made combination sequences are accurate enough, it'll be only 128 different combinations to go through: https://pastebin.com/RZxQkqen

Comment: @HugoBDesigner That list seems to skip over 13xxx. C(10,5) = 252 should be correct, as mentioned by Jaap

Comment: It's helpful to know that there are only so many solutions, and trying them out is easy enough, but I'm having a hard time coming up with a system so I'm 100% sure I get through all of them. (I went through @HugoBDesigner's list, but none of the opened the locks.)

Comment: Sorry about that, seems I wasn't as careful as I had hoped. Here's the updated list, and indeed there are only 252 possible combinations: https://pastebin.com/RZxQkqen and @Ravn since you tried all of the previous list's items, here's the ones I missed out, separated from the whole: https://pastebin.com/tzBbHrNa

Comment: @Ravn Why not iterate in lexicographic order?

Comment: [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Cycling_through_states_with_minimal_effort)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because we want to choose 5 of 10 digits, there will be $${10 \choose 5} = \frac{10!}{5!5!} = 252$$
possibilities.

Now the fun part is how do we do the bruteforce? To minimize the time taken, we can arrange the combinations in such a way that the different digit between each two combinations is only 1 (e.g. after 01234 then can be 01235 or 91234.)

Using lexicographical order doesn't satisfy it as 01239 will goes to 01243 (it changed 2 digits.) To make it efficient, I have written a simple program that generate a possible sequence of 252 combination such that the different digit between each two combinations is only 1.

The program is here: [program](https://ideone.com/1oCR3w)

And the result is here: [result](https://pastebin.com/qP7rtMnE)

Some excerpts:

```
1: 56789
2: 46789
3: 45789
4: 45689
5: 45679
6: 45678
7: 35678
8: 35679
9: 35689
10: 35789
11: 36789
12: 34789
13: 34689
14: 34679
15: 34678
16: 34578
17: 34579
18: 34589
19: 34569
20: 34568
21: 34567
22: 24567
23: 24569
...
```

**Bonus**: If above list doesn't open the lock, then maybe it's not 5 of 10. Can be 4 of 10 or 6 of 10. In that case, update the value of N in my program and run it. For example, using `#define N 4`.

I guess, changing exactly one digit (therefore "pushing" two digits -- push out removed digit, pushed in new digit) and test the lock requires around 3 seconds. Therefore the time taken will be $252 \times 3 \approx 13~minutes$.

Comment: After cycling through all 252 5-digit combinations and 192 of the 210 4-digit combinations, the first of the two locks finally opened (0157 was the code)! Thank you so much for the help, that program was amazingly helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I too have one of these locks.  But after going the all possible 4 digit combinations I was unable to get it open. 
The lock can be disassembled while still locked. By tapping on the backs of the pins, the front panel will come off. Once the is apart, you'll notice there is a slight difference in the position on the notch on 4 of the 10 pins. This is how I determined the code was 2357 for my lock. Now you have the option to keep the original code of change it by simply relocating the pins.

Comment: Actually, in some cheap locks the keys which are not part of the code act as a no-op (i.e. pressing them does nothing). So technically you can open the lock by pressing all 10 keys at once.